# search and replace in simple regular expression

Tags: regex, replace

input:

```
______ - Copy (12)
______ - Copy (5)
______ - Copy (254)
```

and so on
to:

```
a12a
a5a
a254a
```

or in other words to replace what's before and after the number with "a"

*I am using Notepad++*

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search for

```
^.*\((\d+)\).*$
```

and replace with

```
a\1a
```

This assumes parentheses around the number. If those are not necessarily present, use this as a search string (with the same replace string):

```
^.*\b(\d+)\b.*$
```

Comment: I think this would be sufficient: "\\((\d+\)\\)" .  No need for the .* before and after.  They (at least the leading .*) would just cause needless backtracking.  If the OP wants a more exact match it could be "- Copy \\((\d+\)\\)"

Comment: @ElroyFlynn: But he wants to remove all the stuff before and after the number so I have to match it. Backtracking should be minimal.

Answer (score 1):

Search for something like:

```
______ - Copy \(([0-9]+)\)
```

And replace with:

```
a\1a
```